# scan a file using python for a specific string

Tags: email, python-2.7

This is related to my question about writing to an xml document. Im trying to read from an email file (txt/html) doesnt matter on format, what I would like to know is how do I look for a specific string (i.e. my build) that is never in the same place twice and has an associated string as well that is of interest to me? BTW, I'm writing this script in python. I can provide an example of the type of email that I'm referring to when it comes to looking for the information that Im trying to use.

My Code as it sits:

```
    with open('Daily Build Email  07012013.txt','r') as x:
      b = 1
      linka = b
      linkm = b
      for line in x:
        print b,' + ',line
        if "Link1" in line:
         linka = line
         string.strip (s[Link1: ])
         print "Link is ", linka
        #else:
        #   continue
        if "Link2" in line:
         linkb = line
         print "Link is ", linkm
        else:
            continue
        b += 1

x.close()
```

The string strip is to only make the line contain the network location for linka and linkm, because of the leading characters in the line before the \ in the opened file I need to remove those characters so the lines only contain the links in them. Plus I will need to write both links to another file (build.xml) so I can use the build.xml file to automate the test process every time I get a new build email. Plus I will need to also allow for 2 or more builds per email msg (not sure on this just yet).

Comment: You might want to include a sample input and output, to clarify exactly what you want, and also, how far have you gotten on this code so far?

Comment: done, hope you are happy with the added content

Answer (score 0):

I think your main problem is your string.strip - I'm assuming you've seen that in documentation somewhere. the word `string` in `string.strip` is not meant to be there literally, it's meant to be replaced with the name of the string you want to strip. You are telling that string (in this case, probably linka) to strip the leading characters from itself. It takes a list of characters, not a string. It also does not modify the string itself, but returns a new string, which you can put in the same variable, or another. I think what you're after is more likely to be something like string.replace(fromstr,tostr), in this case, `linka=linka.replace("Link1: ","")`

Assuming b is a line-counter, you probably don't want the `else: continue` either - that skips the rest of the loop, so b is not incremented.

Also, you should read up on regular expressions - regex - they are perfect for what you are trying to do here. They have a steep learning curve (especially if you try to start with practical examples, they can be very hard to read at first), but are well worthwhile, and perfect for something like this.

I realise there is probably debugging code in there.

I would rewrite all of the above as follows:

```
import re
for line in open('Daily Build Email  07012013.txt','r'):
    match=re.match(r'Link1: (.*)',line)
    if (match):
            linka = match.group(1)

    match=re.match(r'Link2: (.*)',line)
    if (match):
            linkb = match.group(1)
```

So the main thing that is different (other than stripping all the debugging code...) is the use of regular expressions - using the module `re`. The instruction `match=re.match(r'Link1: (.*)',line)` is where all the magic happens. `Link1: (.*)` is the pattern to look for. In patterns, letters generally stand for themselves - it searches for `Link1:` at the beginning of the string (in this case, the beginning of line`. A single dot`.`can represent any character, and a`*` means, 0 or more. So the bit between the brackets says look for any number (including 0) of any character. Regular expressions, unless other wise specified, are "greedy" - they match as much as possible. So this will match to the end of the line. Because this bit is in brackets, they are assigned to a "group" (more on this later).

So this re.match will search the second parameter (line) and will try to match the pattern. If it finds a match, it returns information about that match, otherwise it returns None.

On the next line, we say `if (match):` - matches pass this test, None fails, so this code block is only run if there was a match. We get group(1) from the match (i.e. the the bit in the first [and in this case only] set of brackets - the information after the  "Link1: " we put it in linka, and, hey! we're done!

Repeat the same for Link2/linkb.

Then, go on to the next line.

Done!